# Initializing Class with {0}

Tags: c++, debugging, class, memory

I´m running a legacy c++ MFC software  into DevPartner Studio and they complain a lot about these lines:

```
PARAFORMAT pf = {0};
```

Where PARAFORMAT is a Class. Any class that is initialized this way, the DevPartner popups this error:

```
Write Overrun: Memory write to 0x002B9D18 (152) overruns local variable pf 0x002B9D14 (156) in function CServerWnd::OnInitDialog; parameter 1 in call to memset.
```

Looks obvious to me that is overriding the right variable.
This construction is right ? I can safely ignore the warnings ?

EDIT:
Here is PARAFORMAT

```
typedef struct _paraformat
{
    UINT    cbSize;
    DWORD   dwMask;
    WORD    wNumbering;
    WORD    wEffects;
    LONG    dxStartIndent;
    LONG    dxRightIndent;
    LONG    dxOffset;
    WORD    wAlignment;
    SHORT   cTabCount;
    LONG    rgxTabs[MAX_TAB_STOPS];
} PARAFORMAT;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing PARAFORMAT, here's my take on what happens.

PARAFORMAT is a POD struct/class with a size of 156 bytes. Your initializer syntax forces the compiler to generate code to initialize all members of the class. All members of the class will effectively have 0 written when initialized.

So, the compiler sets the initial 0 that you specified in the initializer-list, and then is clever and memset's the rest of the struct to 0 instead of setting each member variable individually.

This memset call is caught by a check in DevPartner - it doesn't like that something memsets your local variable without you calling memset, and generates a warning.

So, pending more information, I'd say this is a broken check in DevPartner, which you can ignore. I'll reserve the right to change my mind if/when you provide the rest of the info we need :)

EDIT:

After seeing the PARAFORMAT struct I believe that the above description is correct.

Comment: Nice answer ! I put PARAFORMAT in the topic for you check !

Comment: @bratao: OK, I think that check is faulty - the use of the initializer list is correct and well defined. I'd say just ignore those warnings (or tell the DevPartner people to fix their stuff)

Answer (score 1):

generally speaking: you can only initialize a POD like that, a class is initialized by its constructor.

Comment: I put PARAFORMAT in the topic